# Why do we prefix SQL to the attribute of implicit cursor?

Tags: oracle10g, cursor

Cursor has four attributes like

- `%rowcount`
- `%found`
- `%notfound`
- `%open`

Why do we prefix SQL to the attribute of implicit cursor? 
eg:

```
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || 'row(s) deleted');
```

Answer (score 3):

- Because it's required: if you don't, you'll get a syntax error.
- Because that's what the name of the implicit cursor is.
- SQL stands for [Structured Query Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), which is the language used to specify a query (or DML) run by a cursor.
- Because it's only 3 letters to type, as opposed to `THE_IMPLICIT_CURSOR_FOR_THE_LAST_SQL_STATEMENT_EXECUTED%ROWCOUNT`
- Because Oracle says so, and that's final :)